# is "If link is not clickable, copy and paste it into the address bar" really required for verification mails?

Tags: registration, email, signup-signon, verification

I want to make my verification email (or account activation email) really [neat](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/68372/57501) with just one "confirm your account" button. However most of the times I've  seen that verification email contains below mentioned part.

> If the above link is not clickable, try copying and pasting it into the address bar of your web browser.

Is this part really required?
Do we have some statistics around this?

Comment: FWIW, we've tried this copy-paste link approach in our verification emails and found out that around 2.5% people use this option. We decided to keep this option in the email.

Answer (score 6):

There are several reasons why it's beneficial, from both a UX and a business point of view.

The main UX reason being - not all email clients can handle HTML emails. This is less of an issue these days but it's still a fact. There are hundreds of email clients out there, on loads of different devices. Some browser-based, some OS based, some 3rd-party client based, in-house corporate ones... You have no idea what email client people are using. And you also have no idea if they've opted to disable HTML emails themselves, which [a quick Google search shows is something people do want to do](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=disable+HTML+emails). If these people don't have HTML emails then they won't be able to activate your service. Plain text links negate that risk.

And from a business perspective it's risky to leave these out too. Sending emails in pure HTML is a trigger for some spam-detectors who will just block the email outright.

You'll probably still reach *most* of your target audience with HTML. But reaching 'most' isn't as good for business as reaching 'all' (or as close to all as you can get).

Comment: Do we have any data how many people 'actually' uses links by copy pasting it (maybe someone created different verification links just to track these stats)? Thanks.